# Nested string replace with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, nested

I've got a bunch of HTML pages, in which I'd like to convert CSS-formatted text snippets into standard HTML tags. e.g `<span class="bold">some text</span>` will become `<b>some text</b>`

I'm stuck at nested `span` fragments:

```
<span class="italic"><span class="bold">XXXXXXXX</span></span>
<span class="italic">some text<span class="bold">nested text<span class="underline">deep nested text</span></span></span>
```

I'd like to convert the fragment using Python's regex library. What would be the optimal strategy to regex search-&-replace the above input?

Comment: Why must it be done by regular expression?

Comment: It's just a personal preference. I know it could be done with recusive plain string search... But somehow I find regex solutions to be more elegant...

Comment: The optimal strategy would really be to use something other than regular expressions, which are terribly underpowered for this. [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is the most popular go-to solution for parsing HTML in Python.

Comment: It probably won't be so elegant.  To do tag balancing, you need something stronger than regex.  If you still want to use regular expressions, you'll need to use a loop.

Comment: @hwnd I'm using the following regex pattern: `<span class="(?P<css_class>[^"]+)">(?P<content>[^[]+)</span>` . I'm replacing the tags based on `css_class` - all the CSS classes have their replacement tags in a `dict` object

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the heads up. I found [this C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3921471/1656343) solution. Wondering how to translate it to my python code...

Comment: The ultimate html-regex rant is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3030305).

Answer (score 1):

My solution using lxml and cssselect and a bit of Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cssselect  # noqa
from lxml.html import fromstring


html = """
<span class="italic"><span class="bold">XXXXXXXX</span></span>
<span class="italic">some text<span class="bold">nested text<span class="underline">deep nested text</span></span></span>
"""

class_to_style = {
    "underline": "u",
    "italic": "i",
    "bold": "b",
}

output = []
doc = fromstring(html)
spans = doc.cssselect("span")
for span in spans:
    if span.attrib.get("class"):
        output.append("<{0}>{1}</{0}>".format(class_to_style[span.attrib["class"]], span.text or ""))
print "".join(output)
```

Output:

```
<i></i><b>XXXXXXXX</b><i>some text</i><b>nested text</b><u>deep nested text</u>
```

**NB:** This is a naive solution and does not produce the correct output as you'd have to keep a queue of open tags and close them at the end.

Comment: Awesome! I was unaware of cssselect until now! Thanks @James Mills !

Comment: Oops! It doesn't work as expected.. the output should be: `<i><b>XXXXXXXX</b></i><i>some text<b>nested text<u>deep nested text</b></u></i>`

Comment: Yes my solution is naive at best. You'll have to keep a queue of open tags and close them at the end. I'm sure you can do this? :) Updated my answer to reflect this. (*Have to leave you a little work!*)

Comment: You're right I'm exploring csselect & spyda. Thanks for the heads up!